# php header file working well on localserver (wamp server) but not working well on online server (000webhost)

Tags: php, file, header, refresh

Header file works well on local server (wampserver) but doesn't work on 000webhost.

Here is the code:

```
header("refresh:4   url=http://localhost/www.paytoservice.com/login.php");
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't work"? What's the error?

Answer (score 0):

000Webhost is notorious for disabling random functions/features randomly. So it's possible it might be disabled altogether.

```
header( "refresh:4;url=http://www.paytoservice.com/login.php" );
```

If the code you posted is from your live site, you need to remove the localhost aspect from the domain name and this should work though.

Edit

```
header("Refresh:42;URL=http://www.paytoservice.com/login.php", true, 301);
```

Comment: Try adding secondary to it. Check my post.